# How to access nested class member function from enclosing class where all the members are public in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11, inner-classes, virtual-functions

I am using nested classes in a sensor library development and running into errors. Below is sample code and explanation.

MainClass.cpp

```
class MainClass
{
 public:      
     class nested_class;
     void func1(){
       nested_class1.print();
     }
};
```

NestedClass.cpp

```
class MainClass::nested_class
{
 public:
      virtual void print() = 0;
};
```

Nested1.cpp

```
class nested_class1: virtual public MainClass::nested_class{
    public:
        void print();
};
void nested_class1::print(){
        cout<<"This is for 1\n";
    }
```

Nested2.cpp

```
class nested_class2 : virtual public MainClass::nested_class{
    public:
    void print(){
        cout<<"This is  for 2";
    }
};
```

I am trying to use it to extend the concept of abstraction in my sensor library. But on doing so following is the error:
**print() was not declared in this scope**.

I am newbie to this concept and hence having a hard time finding the issue here. Where am I going wrong here? I can provide more details if required.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't inherit from an incomplete class type.

Comment: Only some general hints: public inheritance within a more global scope of class internal classes might be a design flaw in general and solely for your specific code here, the virtual inheritance is not required very likely. Further on, you should tag your print() method with override within the derived classes in order to make things clearer here.

Comment: @Secundi Clearing the requirement for virtual inheritance: I have a sensor library that intends to serve its functionality across different platforms. So same function will have implementation for different frameworks and hence is inevitable in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nested_class1.print();` isn't how you'd call the `print` member of an instance of `nested_class1`, even if it were declared before there.

The definition of `MainClass::func1` must be after the definition of `nested_class1`, which must be after the definition of `MainClass::nested_class`.

```
#include <iostream>

class MainClass
{
 public:      
     class nested_class;
     void func1();
};

class MainClass::nested_class
{
 public:
      virtual void print() = 0;
};

class nested_class1: virtual public MainClass::nested_class{
    public:
    void print();
};

class nested_class2 : virtual public MainClass::nested_class{
    public:
    void print();
};

void MainClass::func1() {
   nested_class1 obj;
   obj.print();
}

void nested_class1::print(){
    std::cout<<"This is for 1\n";
}

void nested_class1::print(){
    std::cout<<"This is  for 2";
}

int main(){
    MainClass instance;
    instance.func1();
}
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1411dc97dbf818ec)

Comment: I understand this can be followed if all classes are placed in same folder. How would the order matter in case where all the classes lie in different source files? I have a huge sensor library which is spread across different files and hence the question.

Comment: The definition of `MainClass` needs to be `#include`d to define `nested_class1` (and 2), and the definition of `nested_class1` needs to be included to define `MainClass::func1`

Comment: Traditionally this is done by having class definitions in header files (generally .h or .hpp), and class member function definitions in non-header files (generally .cpp)